# running ansible role handler conditionally

Tags: ansible

I have a task that triggers a role handler just fine and the handler works as well.  Now, I am trying to ensure that the handler only runs when a condition is met.  In my case, its a variable value that I am reading via vars_input.  However, I am getting an exception.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

**task example (in role/tasks/main.yml file):**

```
- name: test conditional handler
  command: /bin/true
  notify:
   - test handler
```

**handler (in role/handlers/main.yml file):**

```
---
- name: test handler
  uri: 
    url: http://validurl
    method: GET
  when: {{ test_var }} != "some value"
```

I can access the test_var value in the task.

**exception:**

```
Points to the "!=".  
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with missing quotes.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use the curly braces notation (e.g. `{{ test_var }}`) inside a when statement because the value is interpreted as a Jinja2 expression. The following will work:

```
when: test_var != "some value"
```